# Order Levels (format: numbers) in a factor from low to high in RStudio

Tags: r

I have a problem in R. I have created a factor (called reference). But the Levels are not in the right order; I want them to be in order from low to high (1,2,3...30). I tried reference<-relevel(reference,1) but then the order is not right. Is there a way how I can change the order as I want?

```
reference
  [1] 5  5  1  5  5  5  1  1  1  1  1  11 1  1  1  5  1  5  1  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  3  1  2  1  2  15 2  2  2  15
 [39] 16 3  2  2  4  2  16 23 2  14 2  4  2  3  2  14 4  24 2  2  2  2  3  4  3  3  3  3  25 3  2  3  3  3  3  3  25 3 
 [77] 3  3  3  1  3  15 3  3  3  3  3  1  1  3  8  4  4  4  4  8  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  8  4  4  4  4  8  4  4 
[115] 4  4  15 8  4  16 8  16 14 14 5  5  5  5  7  5  16 5  14 16 14 14 5  5  5  5  14 5  3  5  7  8  4  7  5  5  6  4 
[153] 4  15 15 15 6  4  6  14 4  14 15 6  4  11 6  28 16 6  16 15 9  14 6  14 15 6  16 14 7  14 16 16 16 16 7  7  14 16
[191] 16 7  15 7  4  15 7  15 14 15 15 9  14 7  16 15 15 15 16 14 8  8  9  4  8  8  10 8  4  7  8  4  8  4  8  8  8  8 
[229] 8  8  9  8  8  4  8  8  14 8  8  8  29 14 29 9  29 14 9  16 29 10 29 14 16 9  9  29 29 29 9  29 16 4  4  9  15 29
[267] 9  23 29 9  10 4  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 14 5  10 10 15 11 10 11 10 10 11 11 11 15 4  10 15 10 10 11 11 10
[305] 10 10 11 11 10 11 11 10 11 11 11 10 11 10 8  11 10 10 11 11 10 10 11 11 10 11 14 16 7  15 12 14 14 15 15 14 14 14
[343] 12 17 11 2  15 16 7  16 15 15 15 14 17 28 5  7  17 16 11 13 13 11 13 13 13 13 16 13 13 13 11 13 15 13 13 13 11 13
[381] 13 13 10 13 13 13 13 13 13 10 11 14 15 14 4  14 14 15 8  14 4  4  14 14 14 15 15 14 4  4  14 4  4  4  14 7  8  14
[419] 11 11 15 15 16 3  5  11 15 14 15 15 4  3  15 4  15 15 15 14 14 15 16 15 14 15 11 15 15 15 15 16 7  4  16 16 16 14
[457] 15 14 16 16 16 16 15 12 4  4  4  14 16 16 15 15 14 26 16 26 14 16 4  13 17 21 17 21 17 17 17 17 17 20 17 21 17 17
[495] 18 17 18 17 18 21 17 21 20 18 21 18 18 20 17 17 17 20 17 17 18 18 18 20 18 18 21 18 21 17 17 17 18 18 21 18 17 18
[533] 17 21 17 20 18 22 18 20 19 18 18 19 4  19 18 19 19 15 1  19 17 7  3  20 17 19 19 19 20 18 19 19 19 19 20 18 15 14
[571] 21 20 20 20 20 22 20 20 19 20 20 20 20 20 22 20 21 18 20 20 21 21 17 18 21 20 20 18 20 20 21 17 21 21 22 21 20 20
[609] 21 21 21 21 17 21 18 21 17 18 17 20 20 18 20 20 18 21 21 21 20 17 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 22 21 22 22 22 21 22 22 21
[647] 22 22 21 29 21 22 22 22 22 22 22 20 18 22 8  15 4  4  15 4  4  15 15 15 4  4  4  15 4  15 15 23 4  23 4  2  8  23
[685] 4  23 10 2  4  7  4  7  18 24 15 15 26 11 15 15 4  24 7  15 15 5  24 15 4  1  4  8  24 23 23 6  4  3  23 4  5  1 
[723] 1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  3  2  1  5  1  2  2  1  1  1  20 2  3  25 2  1  3  15 15 15 14 14 14 5  14 15
[761] 4  18 14 8  26 4  15 20 10 16 8  4  15 15 16 4  23 18 15 4  27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
[799] 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28
[837] 28 28 28 28 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 30 30 30 30
[875] 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
Levels: 26 28 27 29 3 30 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the factors to numbers and then factors again :

```
reference <- factor(as.numeric(as.character(reference)))
```

Or if you already know the range of factors :

```
reference <- factor(reference, 1:30)
```